# getting 'NoApiKeys' error after adding key restriction in console

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As it's not a good practice to publish your key when including the Google Maps library, I've removed the key from the include link in my project and added my site IP to the key restriction list of my API key (to which I've added a billing credit card).
Since then, I'm constantly getting the 'NoApiKeys' warning on my site.

What am I missing?
Why there isn't a simple example on Google's site for this? 
(all examples show to add the key to the link, but the best practices page says to avoid it)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you working from a port on the IP?

Comment: For the Google Maps JavaScript API v3, the key must be publicly available on the web page. Best practice is to restrict the key to URLs you control.

Comment: yes, I'm currently working from a port. I temporarily removed it but the error remained.
returning the key to the link won't load the map at all, giving error: 'RefererNotAllowedMapError'

Comment: Look at browser console error message. It typically says which referrer you have to authorize.

Comment: Restricting your key to your IP in the developers console is a good idea but that ip will be authorized for **THAT SPECIFIC KEY** so why would you remove it from your API call?!

Comment: from google's 'best practice' and from other sites that don't include their key, I understood that you only need to include the library, and by permitting my site I thought it would bind the two. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For the Google Maps JavaScript API v3, the key must be publicly available on the web page. Best practice is to restrict the key to URLs you control.

According to Google's [Best practices for securely using API keys](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037)

> When you use API keys in your applications, take care to keep them secure. Publicly exposing your credentials can result in your account being compromised, which could lead to unexpected charges on your account. To keep your API keys secure, follow these best practices:
>
> - Restrict your API keys to be used by only the **IP addresses**, **referrer URLs**, and mobile apps **that need them: By restricting the IP addresses, referrer URLs**, and mobile apps that can use each key, you can reduce the impact of a compromised API key. You can specify the hosts and apps that can use each key from the console by opening the Credentials page and then either creating a new API key with the settings you want, or editing the settings of an API key.

Comment: I've seen this post, and tried to implement, but if i define key restrictions in the google console and include the library with the key it fails to load.

Comment: What is the error you get in the JavaScript console when it doesn't load?

Comment: the error I got is 'RefererNotAllowedMapError '.
does anyone know how to contact google's support about this matter?
I think refining the console's syntex and allowing to define URLs AND server IPs can really help for people that are working on pre-production versions

Comment: That means that now you have a key, but it is not allowed to be used on your website. Your website is not on the list of allowed referrers.  The error message should also tell you the referer that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!

Apparently the google console isn't very friendly and the example given when trying to add key restrictions is bad (...and google should feel bad).

In summery: when adding your domain instead of typing *.example.com/** type the domain fully: https://example.com/* (or any version that corresponds to your domain as it is accessed from the world).

hope this post shortens someone's misery.
Cheers.

Comment: I don't who downvoted this post, but if you see this let me know what I did wrong and if this is not something that can help others.